# how to find the name of certain waterbodies by reverse-geocoding click on map

Tags: google-maps, reverse-geocoding, gis

My problem is, giving the latitude and longitude, the result from reverseGeocoding only provide the detail info of our address, which always contains a nearby street name but not the name of water-bodies. (lake or river)

For example, when we send `(44.934366, -83.797299)` to the server, we expect to get a lake name, which would be "Beaver Lake". However, it only returns the following several types of address:  `"street_address", "administrative_area_level_3", "administrative_area_level_2", "administrative_area_level_1", "political", "postal_code" and "country"`.

Do we have any method to shield the information for street and only focus on geographical features?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at geonames? You should be able to get bodies of water with it. http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#ocean